# Set the datacontext of a usercontrol within a usercontrol no matter how many layers of usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, mvvm-light

I'm currently creating an application that would test the flexibility of WPF. I have some usercontrols that were intended to be quite transparent when it comes to its ViewModel. What I mean by transparent is that the usercontrol can use any type of ViewModel provided that the ViewModel has all the required properties that would be binded to the controls within that usercontrol. I do this by assigning the ViewModel as datacontext for the certain usercontrol.

This works when there are only two usercontrols (one has access to ViewModelLocator, one requires a datacontext declaration from the former). I don't know what to do when it reaches 3 layers of usercontrols or more. Is there a way to set a datacontext of a usercontrol within a usercontrol which resides in a usercontrol that has access to the ViewModelLocator?

Below are some code that would clarify my question.

This code is the parent usercontrol. It was intended to be used on an application that utilizes MAF. I used a non-static ViewModelLocator to make sure that each plugin instance uses a different instance of ViewModelLocator and because the plugin would not have its own app.xaml (thus no global resource). As you can see, I placed a usercontrol from a separate assembly in the grid, then declared its datacontext so that the said usercontrol would interact with the parent usercontrol's ViewModelLocator.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.Inventory.Common.Views.MaterialsNewView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestApp.Inventory.Common.ViewModel"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TestApp.Inventory.Common.Views"
             xmlns:viewsSupp="clr-namespace:TestApp.Supplier.Common.Views;assembly=TestApp.Supplier.Common"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="607" Width="616" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="MaterialsNewView" Source="{StaticResource Locator}" />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <views:SupplierView x:Name="supplierView" Margin="145,306,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="328" Height="258" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=SupplierView}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then I have the code for the child usercontrol. Like what I said earlier, the child usercontrol was intended to be transparent in terms of the ViewModel. That's why the datacontext should be declared in the parent usercontrol every time.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.Supplier.Common.Views.SupplierView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore" Height="289" Width="352" 
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:TestApp.Lookup.Common.Views;assembly=TestApp.Lookup.Common">

    <Grid>
        <my:MaterialTypeListView Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="materialTypeListView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My problem is when the child usercontrol has its own child usercontrol. I don't know how to declare its datacontext from the parent usercontrol. The objective is no matter how many layers of usercontrol are there, they should interact with the ViewModelLocator of the parent usercontrol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `DependencyProperty` to the UserControl SupplierView named MaterialTypeList.

```
public partial class SupplierView
{
    public List<string> MaterialTypeList
    {
        get { return (List<string>)GetValue(MaterialTypeListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaterialTypeListProperty, value);}
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaterialTypeListProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MaterialTypeList", typeof(string), typeof(SupplierView),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Add binding on UserControl MaterialNewView on SupplierView to MaterialTypeList

```
 <UserControl x:Class="TestApp.Supplier.Common.Views.SupplierView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
            mc:Ignorable="d ignore" Height="289" Width="352" 
            xmlns:my="clr-namespace:TestApp.Lookup.Common.Views;assembly=TestApp.Lookup.Common">

        <Grid>
            <my:MaterialTypeListView 
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=MaterialTypeList}"
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="materialTypeListView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Add binding on UserControl SupplierView on MaterialTypeListView to MaterialTypeList.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="TestApp.Inventory.Common.Views.MaterialsNewView"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestApp.Inventory.Common.ViewModel"
                 xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TestApp.Inventory.Common.Views"
                 xmlns:viewsSupp="clr-namespace:TestApp.Supplier.Common.Views;assembly=TestApp.Supplier.Common"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d" Height="607" Width="616" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

        <UserControl.Resources>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
        </UserControl.Resources>

        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <Binding Path="MaterialsNewView" Source="{StaticResource Locator}" />
        </UserControl.DataContext>

        <Grid>
            <views:SupplierView x:Name="supplierView" Margin="145,306,0,0" 
MaterialTypeList="{Binding [HERE YOUR LIST OF MATERIALTYPE]}"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="328" Height="258" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=SupplierView}" />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However the two usercontrols use different ViewModels. I was hoping that there is a way for the MaterialTypeListView to communicate with the ViewModelLocator being accessed by MaterialsNewView to get whatever ViewModel is appropriate for it, and if possible, declare its binding from MaterialsNewView.

Comment: Changed my answer. In short add a DependencyProperty to the uc:SupplierView to which you bind the materialtypelist.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to WPF and I don't quite understand how DependencyProperty would solve my concern. Can you elaborate it a little and provide sample codes if possible? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now. I'll try them out once I get back in the office then get back to you.

Comment: It worked! I've been looking for ways for several days now. This worked like a charm. You're awesome! Thank you very much! :D